# Cannot resolve method 'combinations' in 'Sets'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-2, maven-3

I was trying to build a project in Intellij-idea with Maven and got a error saying that
`"Cannot resolve method 'combinations' in 'Sets'`

The code where the error is showing is here :
[image: Code!]

```
public Set<Set<String>> GetCombinationsSet(){
        System.out.println("Mapper: Calculating combinations");
        ArrayList<String> resources = new ArrayList<>(timeHarMap.keySet());
        Set<Set<String>> combinations = Sets.combinations(ImmutableSet.copyOf(resources), 2);
        //System.out.println(combinations.toArray().length);
        return combinations;
    }
```

The imports im using :

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
```

I have guava dependency in the pom.xml, tried putting this dependency but it doesn't work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Image with the error when i try to build it :
[image: Build]

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Does it fail only in IntelliJ IDEA or in the command line Maven as well?

Comment: It looks like `google-collect` was retired some time ago, and `0.5` seems like a pretty old release. I would recommend updating to guava (the official successor of google-collections) and use a more recent release.

Comment: google-collect is more than 10 years old... If need things like that you could take a look at vavr.io / Eclipse Collections / Guava (https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```